# C# SignalR Override Context.ConnectionId

Tags: c#, jquery, signalr

Is it possible to override the `Context.ConnectionId` with SignalR 2.4.1? It's a shame `IConnectionFactory` is no longer available.

I've tried with the code below. `$.connection.id = userId;` just gets ignored, `var userId = Context.QueryString["UserId"]` does get pulled through to the ChatHub, but as `Context.ConnectionId` is read only within the `Connect` method I can't override it.

I wish to retain the `Clients.AllExcept(connectionId).onNewUserConnected(connectionId, userName)` functionality, which only works if the `Context.ConnectionId` is overridden in all cases as simply overwriting the `connectionId` is not enough because SignalR would have the original Guid's therefore would not match the values I am passing.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```csharp
public void Connect(string userName) {
  var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

  if (ConnectedUsers.Count(x => x.ConnectionId == connectionId) != 0) {
    return;
  }

  ConnectedUsers.Add(new Chat.UserDetail {
    ConnectionId = connectionId,
      UserName = userName
  });

  Clients.Caller.onConnected(connectionId, userName, ConnectedUsers, CurrentMessage);
  Clients.AllExcept(connectionId).onNewUserConnected(connectionId, userName);
}

public override Task OnConnected() {
  var userId = Context.QueryString["UserId"];
  return base.OnConnected();
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  var userId = $("#User").attr("data-id");
  var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;
  $.connection.hub.qs = { 'UserId': userId };
  $.connection.id = userId;
  registerClientMethods(chatHub);

  $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
    registerEvents(chatHub);
  });
});
```

Comment: You can't set the connectionId now. Why you just use groups for that matter?

Comment: Because I'm wanting to use groups for the very nature of what they are, not add a single user to a single group. And I don't believe you can use `Clients.AllExcept(connectionId).onNewUserConnected(connectionId, userName)` with Groups.

Comment: But microsoft on the documentation recommends use single user groups as you can see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#single-user-groups

Comment: The issue with that is that in order to database chat history, you have to maintain a connection list, which seems pointless, if you have say 30 users, all with a unique id, each user would just have the one connection id, with a chat history linked to that id. Also deals with users, opening multiple tabs or browsers, which forces a new Guid for the same user.